# How to hide table rows and column on the edges?

Tags: html, css

For example, I have a 82x82 table. But I want to display only central 80x80 part of the table. The hidden table cells would still have some data, I just don't want to display them. My idea was to put the table into a div that would hide unnecessary parts of the table. Like this:

```css
#workspace {
  position: absolute;
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -400px;
  margin-top: -400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

table {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -10px;
  width: 820px;
  height: 820px;
}
```

```html
<div id="workspace">
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

But when I open console in Mozilla I see a part of hidden cells (see the bottom of the table):
[image]

So my question is how to fix that? Or maybe suggest me other ways to hide the unnecessary parts of the table?

P.S. table cells are created with javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nth-child()` selector to get & hide the table elements on the edges.

```css
 tr:first-child,
 tr:last-child,
 td:first-child,
 td:last-child {
   display: none
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking something like this:

```
#workspace {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#workspace > table {
  position: absolute;
  width: 820px;
  height: 820px;
  top: -20px;
  left:-20px;
}
```